# How many sounds do we have In beatbox?

Tags: beatbox

I'm curious to learn more about beatboxing. Can you please enlighten me by sharing how many distinct sounds are typically incorporated in beatboxing?

Comment: Hi! Please check out [this help page about 'subjective' answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). This question suffers a bit from open-endedness ("share whatever thoughts you might have") and from attempting to make a definitive list of something that isn't definitive (one clue is that your own answer says "there is no definitive answer"). If you search the [meta section for 'list'](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=list) you'll find we also have a policy against questions for which the answer is simply a list of items....

Comment: ... because they can be, like this one, impossible to draw hard boundaries around; or (like "list all of Beethoven's piano sonatas") lack any extra useful info.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as a combo of various close-reasons: somewhat opinion-based, too broad to answer definitively, and list-based.

Comment: @AndyBonner I did a research about all beatbox sounds I collected them in a list I can estimate the amount of sounds.If it's ok I can Improve my answer.

Comment: @AndyBonner every sound in beatbox has many variations.If I don't consider it I can tell you the estimated number.

Comment: It is interesting that lying is not a reason to close. "I'm curious to learn more about beatboxing" sounds quite dishonest when it's immediately answered by the same person spamming their own website.

Comment: @ojs I wouldn't go so far to call it lying- asking a question to answer it yourself is allowed and even encouraged, and it's hard to ask the question without pretending you don't already know the answer.  It's still a poorly formed question with the goal of sharing the creator's website either way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no definitive answer to the exact number of beatbox sounds, as beatboxing is a creative and evolving art form that allows for endless possibilities. However, there are several common beatbox sounds and techniques that are widely recognized and used by beatboxers. Here are some of the popular beatbox sounds:

1. Kick drum: Mimicking the sound of a bass drum.
2. Snare drum: Simulating the sound of a snare drum hit.
3. Hi-hat: Replicating the sound of an open or closed hi-hat cymbal.

These are just a few examples, and beatboxers continue to explore and innovate to create new sounds and techniques. With experimentation and practice, beatboxers can develop their unique style and incorporate a wide variety of sounds into their performances.

### [Human Beatbox Sounds](https://www.humanbeatbox.com/techniques/sounds/)

[image]

I couldn't find a website with audio samples that mentioned all the sounds, so I created it myself.

### [All Beatbox Sounds](https://www.beatboxer.ir/all-beatbox-sounds/)

[image]

---

## Update

I apologize for any confusion caused by my previous response. I want to clarify that I did not intend to promote my own website. However, I did come across a PDF file that provides information on beatboxing sounds, specifically mentioning that there are 544 documented sounds. Beatboxing is an ever-evolving art form with a wide range of techniques and possibilities.

### [Beatbox Sound.pdf](https://github.com/smkplus/beatboxer.github.io/files/11924650/Beatbox.Sound.pdf)

Comment: It bothers me that in answer to a really far too broad question, the answer is basically just a plug for your own web site.